# submit form and display form results using magnific-popup

Tags: php, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup. Within the popup I have a form.  On form submit, I would like to display text from the php form processing file. Right now the page just refreshes and not sure what it's hanging on.

```
<form name="subscribe" id="subscribe" class="subscribe" action=""> 
   <p><input name="subscribe" type="checkbox" value="yes">text here</p>
   <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
echo "thanks";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    // open the popup
    $(window).load(function () {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#my-popup',
                type: 'inline'

            },          
          //add options here, 
                closeOnBgClick: false,
                closeOnContentClick:false

        }, 0);
    });

    // close the window no thanks button
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.magnificPopup.close(); 
    });

    // submit form and show results text
    $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: test.php,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert('ok');
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
        });


})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you want to get but:

- you doesnt define a action for your html form, so anybody with JS Block can'not send this form (action="" will refresh the site)
- and when you override the click function for your submit button you can simply try something like:

> $('#submit').click(function() {
>         alert($('#subscribe').val()); // show checkbox value.